# allow input some character in middle of string

Tags: c#, regex

what expression that i should adds to my regex code to allow character "-" on the middle of string? thanks before :)
this regex used for number input.

this sample of valid input:
1,000,000.0xxx <-- valid |
-1,000,000.0xxx <-- valid |
**1.00-2.00** <-- not allowed this time with my current regex below, this is that i want to ask.

this sample of invalid input:
1.00,00 |
-5,000000

here are my current regex codes : 
`/^(-?)(\d*(\.\d+)?|-|\.\.\.|(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))(?!0(?!\.))\d{1,3}(-?,\d{3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)$/`

Comment: done, hope you can help. :)

Comment: Still Confusing !! Do you require positive number and negative numbers regex ..

Comment: range number input ex: "2.00-2.50"

Comment: if it is too complex i suggest you use 2 if statement. 1 is match with number, 2 is else if match with range number end else is alert wrong number, that is more simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to guess what might be desired here, yet I'm guessing that you'd like to pass decimal numbers and positive decimal ranges, which these expressions might be something to look into, maybe:

```
^(?:-?\d{1,3},?)?(?:\d{3},?)*\.[0-9]{1,2}(?:-(?:\d{1,3},?)?(?:\d{3},?)*\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

---

```
^(?:-?\d{1,3},?)?(?:\d{3},?)*\.[0-9]{1,2}$|^(?:-?\d{1,3},?)?(?:\d{3},?)*\.[0-9]{1,2}-(?:\d{1,3},?)?(?:\d{3},?)*\.[0-9]{1,2}$
```

and would probably fail for some unanticipated instances.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gwWHuj/1/)

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pk2i97/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/pk2i97/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(?:-?\d{1,3},?)?(?:\d{3},?)*\.[0-9]{1,2}(?:-(?:\d{1,3},?)?(?:\d{3},?)*\.[0-9]{1,2})?$";
        string input = @"1,000,000.0
-1,000,000.0
100,000,000.0
-1,000,000,000,000.0
1.00-2.00
1.00

1
11
123
0

.00,00
-5,000000";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: with this code i can develop the new one with some another conditions. this is really helping me, thanks a lot.